# If you use a prefix for the first item in a list do all item in the list keep the prefix with out stating it for each one

Tags: business-language

If you use a prefix for the first item in a list do all items in the list keep that pre fix or should each item restate the prefix. This is my example. 
  "This excludes pre-approved sick, vacation, compensatory time, and personal leave." Should all items that need to be pre approved be stated clearly, or is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, I do not believe you would or should use "pre-approved" in front of every word in the list but the ambiguity would need to be addressed in some clearer, less clunky way.  If I were re-writing it, and all items in the list should have the pre-approved prefix, I would state it like this:

> **"This excludes all pre-approved time off, including sick days, vacation, compensatory time and personal leave."**

Answer (score 1):

The statement as written is ambiguous in a few ways. You have a series

- pre-approved sick [time? leave?]
- vacation [time]
- compensatory time
- personal leave

*Sick* is an adjective and cant stand alone, but the noun it modifies is not clear.

*Vacation* can stand alone, but it is not clear if that is the intent.

It is also unclear as to whether anything other than *sick* [time?] needs to be pre-approved. Ironically, sick time or leave is often the very type of absence for which pre-approval is sometimes least possible.

There are ways to make applicability across the board clear.  Assuming you want *pre-approval* to apply to all, you could say

> This excludes pre-approved leaves (sick [or *illness*], vacation, compensatory time, and personal).
>
> or
>
> This excludes pre-approved leaves for
>
> - illness
> - vacation
> - compensatory time
> - personal time